# Expressions of multiplication

Tags: mathematics

1. Five times three equals 15.
2. Five multiplied by three equals 15.

As I know, multiplication is an operation that consists of calculating the result of adding up the multiplicand as many times as indicated by the multiplier.

So in sentence(1), the multiplicand is 3 and the multiplier 5.
in sentence(2), the multiplicand is 5 and the multiplier 3.

Mathematically speaking, although the result is the same, the expressions are basically different.  Do I get it right? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, both would be written as 5 x 3, though one could argue the first *might* mean "five sets of three". Word problems can be ambiguous... but,, as you state, multiplication of numbers is commutative.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I would write the first as 5 x 3 and the second as 3 x 5.